# Prevent auto playback on embeded HTML video

Tags: html, video, embed

I'm working on embedding how-to videos into our CRM/ERP html help files. These help files will only be accessed from within out company and never from the outside by anyone.

I'm fairly new at HTML and after some time on Google I found a snippet of code I was able to use to embed the video file, my issue is the video file plays immediately after the pages loads (using IE 10), I want the video to only play if the user clicks the play button in the embedded video.

Here is the code I used:

```
<video width="1280" height="740" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   <object data="S:\Syteline\Syteline Manuals\Video Guides\Test\TestMP4Vid.mp4" width="1280" height="740">
     <embed src="movie.swf" width="1280" height="740">
   </object> 
 </video>
```

Is there a simple way to prevent the embedded video from playing upon page load and instead only when the user clicks on the play button?

Alternatively I suppose I could create a hyperlink which when clicked causes the video to play in a separate tab, but I was hopping to make the embedded video work.

```
<a href="S:\Syteline\Syteline Manuals\Video Guides\Test\TestMP4Vid.mp4">Video</a>
```

Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can see here that your video shouldn't auto start (the autoplay attribute makes it autoplay): [link on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay). So, probably your movie runs in flash and it starts automatically.

If that is not the case, then please submit also the browser you have this problem.

You also have the option to put an image as a preview of your movie and append the video object after the user clicks on it. There are multiple ways of doing that, my suggestion would be to use jQuery. Like:

```
$("#id_of_your_image").replaceWith('
    <video width="1280" height="740" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        <object data="S:\Syteline\Syteline Manuals\Video Guides\Test\TestMP4Vid.mp4" width="1280" height="740">
            <embed src="movie.swf" width="1280" height="740">
        </object>
    </video>'
);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention my browser. We are using IE 10

Answer (score 0):

assign id to your video :

```
<video id="my_video" width="1280" height="740" controls>
```

and use javascript:

```
document.getElementById("my_video").autoplay=false;
```